# Send notifications using Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions, flutter-dependencies

I have followed this tutorial to recibe notifications and works fine: https://youtu.be/2tjuUwNx6qk

but I was wondering 2 things:

1. How can I send these notifications just to an emulator? I don't want the users to get all of this while I'm testing
2. How can I send this notifications automatically from the server and when the app is closed? The users create some calendar notifications and before the date expires I need to send them something. It should be personal as well

Answer (score 0):

1. To send a message to a specific device (e.g. emulator), you need to know that device's registration token.

```
final fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
```

See [Send a test message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/first-message) for details.

2. Send registration token (obtained in 1.) to an application server. The application server will bind the token to the user and send a message to the user (e.g. to notify the user about the upcoming calendar event). How to implement a server is naturally specific for a use case. See [Your server environment and FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) for more information.

Comment: I followed this tutorial and it's working fine: https://youtu.be/hmJc7Sxq5Nw
but I need to send them these notifications when the app is closed

Comment: any idea? I also saw this package but still don't know how to check for those dates: https://pub.dev/packages/push